# Is it possible to LS for files on a remote branch?

Tags: git

Is it possible to check what files exists on a remote git branch?

Basically, I have removed some files from a develop and a release branch. I want to be 100% sure they have been removed.  I can do this by doing a clean check out but this can take 10 minutes.

It would be nice to just be able to do a `ls` or something similar on the remote branch without having to check the entire thing out.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @GabrielePetronella That is not a duplicate. This question refers to listing the files in a particular branch without checking it out, while that question refers to listing the files in a particular branch without even having a local clone.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the `ls-tree` command.  For example:

```
git ls-tree -tr origin/master
```

---

As pointed out in a comment, this uses the local `origin/master` ref so this assumes that you have run `git fetch origin master` first, or that you have just pushed to this branch.